# ssh redirection

Tags: linux, ssh, nat

I have a burst VPS server and my home computer is behind a NAT. I want to use ssh redirection to connect with my home computer at another place.

I do this in my home computer:

```
ssh -fNgR 2221:localhost:22 root@myvps.info
```

and so there is a sock listen on port 2221 in myvps.info

```
netstat -an 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2221          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

now i want to connect with my home computer with command bellow

```
ssh -p 2221 root@myvps.info
```

but it returned:

```
ssh: connect to host myvps.info port 2221: Connection refused
```

I use nmap myvps.info  to see what port is open on there vps server it shows:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
593/tcp  filtered http-rpc-epmap
4444/tcp filtered krb524
```

on 2221 port open! why and how can i slove this problem?

Comment: Will you be solving it with programming?

Comment: thanks second floor , i don't know there is acceptable answer you can set before.

Answer (score 1):

Your netstat shows "127.0.0.1:2221", which means that it only listens on 127.0.0.1 (local connections). You'll need to configure another listening address, either a ip address of the machine, or 0.0.0.0 which usually means all addresses available.

Comment: how could i configure it ? could you tell me more ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
ssh -fNR *:2221:localhost:22 root@myvps.info
```

which will bind the server's listening socket to all network interfaces (not just localhost), and

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

in your /etc/sshd_config file (the exact path may vary depending on your Linux distribution).

See the [ssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) and [ssh_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) man pages for more information.

Comment: i use the command , ssh -fNR *:2221:localhost:22 root@myvps.info , but the netstat output is still "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2221          *:*               LISTEN "